# Java 8 Install Failure on Windows 10

Tags: windows, java-8

I'm attempting to install Java 8 JRE on Window 10, and it's failing.  The purpose of this is so that I can install SQLWorkbenchJ on my Windows machine.  This is my personal machine, and I have complete access privileges.  Please let me know if I can provide any additional information to answer this question (e.g., logs).

I've downloaded Java 8 from Oracle, specifically the offline 64 bit version for windows.  When I download it, it places the following icon on my desktop:

[image]

When I double click on this icon, the following image pops up:

[image]

After I click "Yes" and the popup box disappears, nothing happens.  Windows continues operating as if nothing happened.  The only trace of activity is in the task manager, which shows the following:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm at a loss for how to push the installation process forward.

Comment: Not sure from where you have downloaded, could you try downloading from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was able to solve this issue by installing the x86 version (32 bit) instead.  I'm not sure why the x64 version doesn't work on Windows 10, but I'd seen this solution subtly referred to elsewhere on the internet as a solution.  Would be interesting if someone could figure out why the x64 version itself doesn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 7 - the 32-bit version worked.

Answer (score 0):

We have two concerns here - 1. JRE 8u101 (64-bit) fails to install without an error message and 2. JRE 8u101 (64-bit) fails to install on Windows 10.

The first one seems similar to http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8148167 which is a known issue. 
However, it would be appropriate to take a look at jusched and JavaDeploy log files to confirm the same.

The second concerns with 64-bit JRE installation in Windows
Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 is not supported a supported browser.

For Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10, see:
Related bug ID: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8162523
For a solution related to 64-bit installation, suggest you to follow the instructions from the comment in the above bug report.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148167 , this has already fixed in 8u111/8u112, early access builds are available here - https://jdk8.java.net/download.html, you can download and try to install the same. Do let us know your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well and the 8u112 worked from this [page](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)

Thank you